# java.lang.IOException:pipe broken

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I am developing a bluetooth file transfer application. In this application, I want to connect two android devices via bluetooth and transfer files. However, I am able to show all nearest device, Paired devices and able to connect with them but when I transfer images, bluetoothSocket.write() throws pipe broken exception. I have searched for solutions and refer all answers from stackoverflow and after that what I understood is that when the receiver bluetooth server socket is closed, this exception is raised but I can't get how to solve this problem. Below is my code for connecting to device and transferring images. Thanks in advance

```
package com.example.jayesh.bluetoothusagedemo.ConnectAsyncTask;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.jayesh.bluetoothusagedemo.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by Jayesh on 26-01-2017.
 */

public class ConnectDevice extends AsyncTask<BluetoothDevice, Void, String> {
    BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    Context context;
    String uuid;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    byte[] bytes;

    public ConnectDevice(Context context,String uuid)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(BluetoothDevice... bluetoothDevices) {

        try {
            bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevices[0].createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(uuid));

            if (bluetoothSocket != null) {
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("socket=======","socket timeout");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(bluetoothSocket.isConnected()){
            convertImageToByteArray();

            try {
                //Log.d("bytessize========", String.valueOf(bytes.length));
                for(Byte b:bytes){
                    if(bluetoothSocket.isConnected()){
                        outputStream.write(b);
                        //Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d("closed=============","true");
                        break;
                    }
                    //outputStream.flush();
                }
                //outputStream.write(bytes);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } //catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            //}
        }

        return "completed...";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //super.onPostExecute(s);
        Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    void convertImageToByteArray(){
        try {
            outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.pic1);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
            bytes = stream.toByteArray();
            Log.d("bytessize========", String.valueOf(bytes.length));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a bluetooth server running on the other device to read the image that you are sending to it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I haven't closed bluetooth socket before writing data to write() and i also checked whether it is closed using bluetoothSocket.isClosed() method before writing data to write().Please check my code

Comment: thanks for reply I have made application to connect and send data only.I haven't made any other that read that data which i have sent..On second device , just bluetooth is on and connected